# Java thread as argument to a class

Tags: java, thread-synchronization

Can I pass a Thread (which runs an instance of a class) to another class which then runs as a Thread too and handle the first from the second?

This is some sample/explain code:

```
 Sender sender = new Sender(client, topic, qos,frequency);
 Thread t1;
 t1= new Thread(sender);
 t1.start();


 Receiver receiver = new Receiver(frequency,client, qos, topic,t1);
 Thread t2;
 t2 = new Thread(receiver);
 t2.start();
```

Both classes implement runnable and I want the sender to call wait himself but the receiver to notify it. I tried it but nothing happens, sender is still in waiting state.

I can provide the whole code if needed.

Comment: Yes, you can pass any object as a parameter. I suspect the problem is in how you are trying to notify it, and/or how you are listening for that notification. Please show that code.

Comment: @AndyTurner It is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47892098/thread-handling-between-seperate-classes where i asked but did not express it corrrectly.

Comment: You should not do this.  Thread is a JDK 1.0 class.  If you're programming concurrency at this low level I'd suggest that you are doing it wrong.  You should be thinking in terms of java.util.concurrency classes and Executors.  Sender/receiver suggests a common pattern that would be better implemented using BlockingDeque or JMS.  Your way would not be recommended by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some stripped down code that does what I think you are asking:

```
public class WaitTest {

    static class Waiter implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Waiting");
            try {
                synchronized(this){
                    this.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Running");
        }

    }

    static class Notifier implements Runnable{

        Object locked;

        public Notifier(Object locked){
            this.locked = locked;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            synchronized(locked){
                locked.notifyAll();
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Waiter waiter = new Waiter();
        Notifier notifier = new Notifier(waiter);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(waiter);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(notifier);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: I will try this. But can't it be done in a more abstract way like the one in my code? Where I don't have a Waiter object in my Notifier?

Comment: This is a possible solution too. I did it in a very similar way, i declared a volatile variable in main and used it as a mutex for waiter and notifier synchronization. If you think volatile is better or worse than the object you used tell me, i want to know.